# Can I use beacontools with Python 3 on Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use **beacontools** lib. It works perfectly with python 2.7, but does not with 3.5.

I'm trying to test it with a code provided in examples

```
import time
from beacontools import BeaconScanner, IBeaconFilter

def callback(bt_addr, rssi, packet, additional_info):
    print("<%s, %d> %s %s" % (bt_addr, rssi, packet, additional_info))

# scan for all iBeacon advertisements from beacons with the specified uuid
scanner = BeaconScanner(callback,
    device_filter=IBeaconFilter(uuid="05f62a3d-f60f-44bc-b36e-2b80fd6c9679")
)
scanner.start()
time.sleep(5)
scanner.stop()
```

What I have got is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/beacontools/scanner.py",
>   lin                     e 98, in run
>       self.set_scan_parameters()   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/beacontools/scanner.py",
>   lin                     e 151, in set_scan_parameters
>       scan_parameter_pkg)
>   _bluetooth.error: (1, 'Operation not permitted')

What is the reason of 'Operation not permitted'? The same code works with python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the Python version, but I faced the same issue too. Running the script with sudo worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run python as root like:

```
$ sudo python3 <your main.py>
```